# Jquery click handler not working in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a Jquery plugin called Jquery Content Panel Switcher.  It does exactly what the title says, it switches out divs with ease.  The html for the page is:

```
<!--The switcher buttons, basic anchor tags, with the switcher class -->
<a id="content1" class="switcher">One</a>
<a id="content2" class="switcher">Two</a>

<!-- The panel you wish to use to display the content -->
<div id="switcher-panel"></div>

<!-- The actual content you want to switch in and out of the panel, this is hidden -->
<div id="content1-content" class="switcher-content show"></div>
<div id="content2-content" class="switcher-content show"></div>
```

In each of my content panels I have a form.  In each form there is a table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" data-controller="rank">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left"><h2>Rank 1</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Requirements</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-name="one_li">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-name="two_li">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>More Info</td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to fire off an action if a row gets clicked.  Here is the javascript I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#switcher-panel form table tbody tr').click(function(){
     console.log("Clicked");
   });
});
```

When I use the Jquery selector of `$('#switcher-panel form table tbody tr')` in my Chrome console, it finds the table and everything looks fine.  When I put it in my javascript file, nothing happens.  Some direction would be great.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('#switcher-panel').on('click', 'table tr', function() {
    console.log("Clicked", this);
});
```

[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/B2rud/)

This adds a listener to the `#switcher-panel` that listens for `click` events on it's children, if the clicked child falls under the `'table tr'` selector.

[Check out this artice](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/) for more info about event delegation. <sup>(Ctrl+f for Event delegation)</sup>

Comment: This didn't work for me but I removed "table " so the second argument is simply "tr" and that worked.

Comment: This is the best solution out of existing.

Answer (score 3):

If the content of the panel is dynamically appended you would need to delegate the click event to a static parent element. Try this:

```
$('#switcher-panel').on('click', 'form table tbody tr', function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

My guess would be you could shorten the child selector to `table tr` as well.